# StreamCorruptedException: unexpected EOF in middle of data block

Tags: java, eof

I am trying to make a client - server program using UDP.
I am able to serialize the message from Server, and client also able to receive the message. But I don't know why, the client doesn't able to deserialize the message.

In server side, i am sending a List to the others nodes.

```
    List<Message> messageToSend = new ArrayList<Message>();
    messageToSend.add(message);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    out.writeObject(messageToSend);
    byte dbByteSend[] = bos.toByteArray();
    out.close();
    bos.close();

    for(Entry<Integer,String> entry: test.getNeighbourList().entrySet()){       
        String IPaddress = entry.getValue();
        Integer portIP = entry.getKey();
            InetSocketAddress IPAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(IPaddress), portIP);
            DatagramPacket sendPacketFirst = new DatagramPacket(dbByteSend,dbByteSend.length, IPAddress);
            Main.serverSocket.send(sendPacketFirst);
    }
```

In the client side, i am receive the message using this code:

```
        clientSocket.receive(client.receivePacket); 
        byte[] b = client.receivePacket.getData();
        List<Message> incomingMessages = gossip.serialization.deserializeByte(b);
```

here is the deserialize code:

```
     public List<Message> deserializeByte (byte[] data){
    List<Message> mapSer = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream filee = new ByteArrayInputStream (data);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(filee);
        mapSer = (List<Message>) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        filee.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mapSer;
}
```

here is byte [] data value:

```
    [-84, -19, 0, 5, 115, 114, 0, 19, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 65, 114, 114, 97, 121, 76, 105, 115, 116, 120, -127, -46, 29, -103, -57, 97, -99, 3, 0, 1, 73, 0, 4, 115, 105, 122, 101, 120, 112, 0, 0, 0, 1, 119, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 115, 114, 0, 14, 71, 111, 115, 115, 105, 112, 46, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, -26, -73, 19, -11, -46, 85, 53, 114, 2, 0, 4, 76, 0, 9, 98, 108, 97, 99, 107, 108, 105, 115, 116, 116, 0, 16, 76, 106, 97, 118, 97, 47, 117, 116, 105, 108, 47, 76, 105, 115, 116, 59, 76, 0, 14, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 116, 0, 19, 76, 106, 97, 118, 97, 47, 117, 116, 105, 108, 47, 84, 114, 101, 101, 77, 97, 112, 59, 76, 0, 16, 110, 101, 119, 78, 101, 105, 103, 104, 98, 111, 117, 114, 76, 105, 115, 116, 116, 0, 36, 76, 99, 111, 109, 47, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 47, 99, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 47, 99, 111, 108, 108, 101, 99, 116, 47, 77, 117, 108, 116, 105, 109, 97, 112, 59, 76, 0, 4, 116, 121, 112, 101, 116, 0, 28, 76, 71, 111, 115, 115, 105, 112, 47, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 36, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 84, 121, 112, 101, 59, 120, 112, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 119, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 115, 114, 0, 17, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 18, -30, -96, -92, -9, -127, -121, 56, 2, 0, 1, 73, 0, 5, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 120, 114, 0, 16, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 78, 117, 109, 98, 101, 114, -122, -84, -107, 29, 11, -108, -32, -117, 2, 0, 0, 120, 112, 0, 0, 0, 9, 120, 115, 114, 0, 17, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 84, 114, 101, 101, 77, 97, 112, 12, -63, -10, 62, 45, 37, 106, -26, 3, 0, 1, 76, 0, 10, 99, 111, 109, 112, 97, 114, 97, 116, 111, 114, 116, 0, 22, 76, 106, 97, 118, 97, 47, 117, 116, 105, 108, 47, 67, 111, 109, 112, 97, 114, 97, 116, 111, 114, 59, 120, 112, 112, 119, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 113, 0, 126, 0, 11, 116, 0, 5, 100, 97, 116, 97, 57, 120, 115, 114, 0, 43, 99, 111, 109, 46, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 46, 99, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 46, 99, 111, 108, 108, 101, 99, 116, 46, 65, 114, 114, 97, 121, 76, 105, 115, 116, 77, 117, 108, 116, 105, 109, 97, 112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 120, 114, 0, 46, 99, 111, 109, 46, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 46, 99, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 46, 99, 111, 108, 108, 101, 99, 116, 46, 65, 98, 115, 116, 114, 97, 99, 116, 76, 105, 115, 116, 77, 117, 108, 116, 105, 109, 97, 112, 91, 110, -123, -4, 93, 54, 46, -91, 2, 0, 0, 120, 114, 0, 50, 99, 111, 109, 46, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 46, 99, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 46, 99, 111, 108, 108, 101, 99, 116, 46, 65, 98, 115, 116, 114, 97, 99, 116, 77, 97, 112, 66, 97, 115, 101, 100, 77, 117, 108, 116, 105, 109, 97, 112, 33, -9, 102, -79, -11, 104, -56, 29, 2, 0, 0, 120, 112, 119, 8, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 9, 0, 0, 8, 57, 119, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 115, 114, 0, 16, 71, 111, 115, 115, 105, 112, 46, 78, 101, 105, 103, 104, 98, 111, 117, 114, 75, 81, 2, 112, -125, -57, 76, 114, 2, 0, 6, 73, 0, 4, 112, 111, 114, 116, 73, 0, 10, 116, 97, 114, 103, 101, 116, 80, 111, 114, 116, 76, 0, 13, 78, 101, 105, 103, 104, 98, 111, 117, 114, 76, 105, 115, 116, 116, 0, 19, 76, 106, 97, 118, 97, 47, 117, 116, 105, 108, 47, 72, 97, 115, 104, 77, 97, 112, 59, 76, 0, 9, 105, 80, 65, 100, 100, 114, 101, 115, 115, 116, 0, 18, 76, 106, 97, 118, 97, 47, 108, 97, 110, 103, 47, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 59, 76, 0, 16, 110, 101, 119, 78, 101, 105, 103, 104, 98, 111, 117, 114, 76, 105, 115, 116, 113, 0, 126, 0, 5, 76, 0, 15, 116, 97, 114, 103, 101, 116, 73, 80, 65, 100, 100, 114, 101, 115, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 23, 120, 112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 81, 112, 112, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 16, 119, 8, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 116, 0, 12, 49, 57, 50, 46, 49, 54, 56, 46, 48, 46, 49, 48, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 80, 112, 112, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 16, 119, 8, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 113, 0, 126, 0, 26, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, -87, 112, 112, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 16, 119, 8, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 113, 0, 126, 0, 26, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 83, 112, 112, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 16, 119, 8, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 113, 0, 126, 0, 26, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 9, 0, 0, 4, 81, 119, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 57, 112, 112, 115, 113, 0, 126, 0, 16, 119, 8, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

when it run mapSer = (List) in.readObject(); it shows an error

```
    StreamCorruptedException: unexpected EOF in middle of data block
```

Can anyone help me and tell me where i did wrong?

i tried to deserialize the message in Server using the same code, and it works, but I don't know why it isn't working in client.

Comment: Show how you serialized that data, and how you acquired that byte array before calling this code.

Comment: I already add my serialize code. I know that i convert it to file first then put it in byte array, but it still work if i deserialize it in the server.

Comment: You still haven't shown where the `byte[]` in the deserialization code came from. Obviously it isn't complete.

Comment: byte  [ ] in the deserialize is called filename, and it have  the value. What do you meant by not shown?

Comment: I mean, and I said, you haven't shown where it came from.

Comment: byte[ ] filename is the byte array that the client received using receivePacket.getData() method. then i called deserializeByte() to convert the byte[ ] into List<Message>. Btw, why you need to know where it came from? because it already have value, so there is no problem with receiving the data, isn't it?

Comment: Please post the code concerned, including the code that initializes the array and the receiving code. Edit it into your question. We need to know where it came from because, ***obviously,*** it is incomplete, as you're getting an`EOFException.`

Comment: I already edit the question. I hope it become clear. what do you think the problem is?

Comment: I specifically asked you for the code that initializes the array. You are wasting time. Somewhere you have declared and initialized a byte array and built a `DatagramPacket` around it. Post that code.

Comment: @EJP I don't have any byte [ ] in server side except `byte dbByteSend[ ]` ( which is the serialised version of the the message that I want to send), that I send using `DatagramPacket sendPacketFirst` to the client. In client side, I received it from `clientSocket.receive(client.receivePacket);` then save the byte array into `byte [ ] b` and deserialize it. I already post the code.

Comment: Don't talk rubbish here. You have a `DatagramPacket`. You therefore have a `byte[]` array which you initialized it with, i.e. passed to its constructor, and which therefore had a declaration and initialization of its own, unless you provided `new byte[...]` as an argument to the constructor. Post that code and stop wasting time.

Comment: oh I see..  thank you for the clue. I solve the problem. My problem is I set different byte[ ] size for sending and receive. that is the reason that cause an error. After change the byte [ ] size, everything works perfectly. once again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The byte[] array you are using to build the receiving `DatagramPacket` is too small.